# How to protect toroidal plasma against air-resistance?

Tags: science-based, physics

I have a plasma rifle, but it's not just any plasma, rifle. This weapon uses accelerates a  [toroid plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spheromak)to incredibly high speeds [I can shot the cup down from anyone's head](https://youtu.be/-VL0M0jmu7k?t=63). (and probably smash their ribcage apart if I miss):

- Speed is 8km/s ( approx. the re-entry speed of columbia).
- I use nitrogen plasma, because it's abundant.
- Projectile weight: 0,31 gram.
- Diameter is 1 decimeter.

But there's a problem, namely air resistance (as the weapon would be fired in an atmosphere), as the toroidal shape isn't the most aerodynamic one, but I'm not entirely sure about the air's effects on it.

**So, how could I protect the plasma from air-resistance, if it's a significant hindrance?**

Comment: Tbo, at those speeds, I'd be less concerned with air-resistance (be aware that relative to your plasma, the air is not moving anymore) and more concerned about dying. The speed should be more than enough to result in nuclear fusion = radiation = everyone is dead in a large radius

Comment: @Raditz_35 Well, that's the goal. Maybe if I lower the speed a bit...

Comment: You would be dead almost instantly if you fired this weapon within the atmosphere. So this is basically a suicide bomb? Worrying about plasma but not about yourself, well, priorities. How far away is your target supposed to be? I personally don't know how to calculate the blast radius from the top of my head, but maybe it would help someone who can.

Comment: @Raditz_35 600 m range, kinetic must be enough to break apart a skull.

Comment: There's some YouTube videos of live stage productions of “standupmaths” shooting enormous vortexes in a theater.

Comment: @JDługosz That's the linked video, and I don't care Secespitus, people should click the links.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you once agian, I've seen that I made an assumption that might have altered how I saw the question. Could you please specify how much plasma you are shooting and the direction of those 2000 km/s - and if this isn't the velocity in the direction of the target - what is that velocity? It also wouldn't hurt to know what your plasma is made out of. But most likely the answer is: There would not be any significant slowing down or change in 600m, there would just be less plasma equal to the amount of atoms in the air and a lot of radiation + some heavier elements

Comment: The one from standupmaths is *bigger*.  Way bigger.  And he includes information about vorex rings and how tney work.

Comment: @Raditz_35 BTW, I'd use fluorine.

Comment: So... I googled DM, and 1 DM, and various other combinations, and each time i came up with different things such as type 1 diabetes, direct messages, designated marksmen, and dungeon master. Luckily, I actually know that 1 dm = 1 decimeter, but how about using more common units in your question next time? 1 decimeter is **10 centimeters**, a unit that most people are much more familiar with.

Comment: @Aify Because we use direct messages, dungeon masters and diabetus to measure diameter.

Comment: Please clarify your units for the toroidal plasma. Is its diameter one decimetre or one dekametre? This is a difference of two orders of magnitude. Just saying cavalierly that's it's 1 dm is unhelpful and renders part of your question meaningless.

Comment: The simplest answer is, of course, only fire your toroidal plasma weapon in a vacuum.

Comment: @Raditz_35 Also note this [xkcd-what if](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/). The speed there is higher than here  but not THAT much (factor 151, only ~2 orders of magnitude), and we're already dealing with plasma here. So I'm pretty that Raditz_35 was correct in his first comment and that the weapon would blow up everything in the surroundings when fired.

Comment: @Nicolai Then let's lower the speed to 60 km/s.

Comment: If you change the speed now you invalidate the only answer you have that's already been upvoted.

Comment: @Aify That's not true, I give you some time to figure out why.

Comment: You're right, I misread your 60 km/s as 60 m/s. Sphennings answer is still correct, and this question is still bad.

Answer (score 7):

Since vortex rings are sustained by aerodynamic interaction they're not going to work past the speed of sound (340.29 m/s).

Best way to protect something from aerodynamic forces is to put it within a fairing of some sort. Such a fairing won't practically contain a plasma. However if you use a copper fairing and fill the inside with lead, it will do an excellent job of damaging whatever it hits.